# Restore mysql Data from Instance Files

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a snapshot of an unreachable ec2 instance. I was able to mount the snapshot as a drive and can access all of the files. My goal is to transfer all of the SQL data from the unreachable instance to my new one. I successfully located folders labeled after my databases' names with .opt, .frm, and .ibd files in /var/lib/mysql. I attempted to copy these folders into my new MySQL folder and while the databases showed up with the table and column names, there was no data and it gave me error 1146 - table doesn't exist. Any idea where my data might be and how I can restore it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to copy the **entire** /var/lib/mysql folder over to the new machine, especially ibdata* and ib_logfile* files, or none of your InnoDB tablespaces (.ibd) will work.

Comment: I copied over the entire folder and got: ./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.php#262
 mysqli_query(): (HY000/1018): Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
and none of my dbs were visible

Comment: You probably need to "chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql"

Comment: What distro? It could be SELinux or AppArmor getting in the way.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: It works now! I just needed to restart mysql (I was restarting apache2). Thanks!